# Eclipse Menu Keyboard Shortcut stopped working

Tags: eclipse, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Eclipse on Windows.

Suddenly <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> stopped opening the Run menu.

There is an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut defined in the Default Scheme, but I believe it has always been there, and "When" is "Terminal widget context". Removing it does not help.

How do I re-activate Alt+R without re-installing Eclipse?

Comment: In the mean time, I can press Alt, let go, and then press R.